# Transformar informação do banco em Link

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou fazendo um site no qual traz uma string do banco mas quero que essa string seja informada da seguinte forma, no lugar dela vai aparecer um botão que o usuário vai clicar e esse botão vai abrir o url que é o texto que ta na string que no caso é o Link para Download.

```
<dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Link)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Link)
            </dd>
```

Aqui eu trago a string item pra aparecer na tela, mas quero que ela seja um botão que abre a URL que é ela mesma.

Comment: Tem um exemplo de como é `string`? ela vem mais ou menos assim: **http://meusite.com.br/alguma_coisa** ou **/alguma_coisa**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o componente chamado `Html.ValueFor`, ele retorna o valor contido no atributo chamado dentro do `href`, e depois estilizar o `<a>`(se quiser pode usar o meu css). Isso é, imaginando que a sua string seja um link mesmo tipo "www.google.com", é só colocar isso na sua View trocando "Clique aqui" pelo texto do seu botão.

```
<a class="button-style" href="@Html.ValueFor(m => m.Link)">Clique aqui</a>
```

Estilo CSS para botão:

```
.button-style {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: fiz o teste e quando cliquei no botão abriu esse link: http://localhost:58611/Items/www.globo.com , no caso a String é www.globo.com

Comment: Quando você da um Debug.WriteLine a string é `www.globo.com` ? certeza?

Comment: @RomãoGomes como ficou seu código lá? parece que ele está montando um `Html.ActionLink`

Comment: sim, me envia teu email pra eu te mandar o projeto por favor.

Comment: @RomãoGomes há necessidade, faz assim coloca um breakpoint no seu controller e printa o model para eu ver que valor está nele.

Answer (score 0):

A maneira mais simples de se fazer é usar tag `<a>` passando sua url vinda na model para o atributo [href](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp). Você também poderá usar classes do [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/) para estilizar seu botão.

```
 <a href="http://@modelItem.Link" class="btn btn-primary">Site</a>
```

```html
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="http://www.google.com.br" class="btn btn-primary">Site</a>
```

Caso queira usar [Razor](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/razor_syntax.asp) você poderá criar seu próprio helper.

```
public static class LinkHelper
{
    public static string ExternalLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string url, string text)
    {
        return String.Format("<a href='http://{0}' target="_blank"  class="btn btn-primary">{1}</a>", url, text);
    }
}
```

Usando o Help.

```
@Html.ExternalLink("www.google.com", "Google")
```

Fonte: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/864248/How-can-I-add-links-to-external-web-sites-in-mvc